# get range between two timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

I like to get the total hours in between two timestamp.
Take a look at my code

```
$sql="UPDATE timekeeping SET end= timestamp(NOW()),totalrange = ((end- begin) - 1)  
WHERE end IS NULL and fullname = '$whoareyou[fullname]'";
```

but in this code "totalhours = ((end- begin) - 1)" is wrong i feel it :)

I want this to show something like this

```
2014-05-07 02:00:38.000000 - 2014-05-07 06:00:38.000000   = 4
```

and something like this

```
2014-05-07 02:00:38.000000 - 2014-05-07 06:30:38.000000   = 4.30
```

but i do not know where or what to do.

Please help anyone. I have done my part in researching and found no suitable answer which I can understand since this was my first time to use php.

Answer (score 1):

The following SQL query should do the trick:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, '2012-06-06 13:13:55', '2012-06-06 15:20:18');
```

Replace the second argument with the date they last logged in and the third argument with the date of their current login.

This will return an integer equal to the hours between the first time stamp and the second time stamp.

EDIT: If you wish to get also the minutes, then replace 'HOUR' with 'MINUTE' and do some math to get the decimal value of Hours.Minutes.

Comment: DidI do it right? Here's what I did Sir....`$sql="UPDATE timekeeping SET actualend = timestamp(NOW()), logoutdate = date(NOW()), totalhours = TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, actualend, actualstart)  WHERE actualend IS NULL and fullname = '$loginuser[fullname]'";`

Comment: Looks good, though run the query on SQL to make sure it returns no errors before applying it in production.